# How to get base64 of local video in expo react native project

Tags: react-native, expo

I am trying to convert video file to base64. How can I achieve such thing. I have gone through a lot of searching for answer but all in vain. I have tried FileSystem.readAsStringAsync() but it works with image and does not return anything when mp4 (video) is passed to it. Or can someone direct me to point that how can I get blob from file uri to send it to server?
Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Create a `formData` and use it like this to send to server

Create a function

```
const CreateFormData = (filePath) => {
  let formdata = new FormData();
  formdata.append('file', {
    name: 'SampleVideo.mp4',
    uri: filePath, // File path
    type: 'video/mp4',
  });
  return formdata;
};
```

Now use it like this

```
const response = CreateFormData("file:///storage/emulated/0/DCIM/b01f3aef-4b56-48d9-b7a2-e3424df0f054.mp4") // Pass here the File uri
```

Now perform a POST request to your Backend/Server with this `response` formData in body